# folding-mode start fully folded?

Tags: code-folding

I tried many different folding plugins for Emacs and ended up using [`folding-mode`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FoldingMode) as I used [Vim's folding marks](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/fold.html) and so my files contain a large number of folding marks. I am currently in the process of switching from Vim to Emacs (`evil-mode`).

However, I miss that my file is fully folded when I open it. Does anyone know how to force `folding-mode` to fold everything when opening a file?

My init file contains:

```
;; folding-mode
(load "folding" 'nomessage 'noerror)
(folding-add-to-marks-list 'ess-mode "/*{{{*/"  "/*}}}*/"  nil t)
(folding-mode-add-find-file-hook)
(add-hook 'ess-mode-hook 'folding-mode)
(evil-leader/set-key "ff" 'folding-toggle-show-hide)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Folding-mode will automatically fold files when opened if you call `(folding-mode-add-find-file-hook)` in your init file.

The documentation, however, seems wrong. It says that you need to specify a file-local variable, but testing suggests that this is not needed.

Comment: I made an edit and put the folding-mode part of my emacs init file into the question. As you can see the option is already included. Still no automatic folding happening.

Comment: Ah ok, I found my error. The order of my options was incorrect. Now it is working.